# Prestashop 1.7: Technical difference between a "custom" feature value and a not custom one?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop 1.7, what is the technical difference between a "custom" feature value and a not custom one (I'm speaking about the boolean field `custom`)?

Because in order to save in DB a feature value, I want to use `add` after having initialized the attributes of my `FeatureValue` object. Among those being this boolean `custom`.

Answer (score 0):

"Custom" feature values are related to specific products and can only be inputed from the product edit page itself and cannot be reused for other products.

Non-custom feature values should be created from Attributes & Features page and can be linked to multiple products at the same time from the "Pre-defined value" dropdown editor in product edit page.

Answer (score 0):

**Faceted module (Product sidebar filter)**

You have to keep in mind that you are able to use Product Pre-defined feature Values as filters on your product page. For example when you have multiple Pre-defined feature Values for "size" you are able to enable these in the Faceted Module of Prestashop and your customers can filter your products by selecting a specific size. This is not supported for custom values.

So the big diffrence is that you can use Pre-defined feature Values as a filter on your product page. Pre-defined feature Values also decrease the change of making typo's while adding products.

When you have a multi langue store it Pre-defined feature Values speeds up the process since you don't have to add every langue manually for each product.